# Bessel function integral

Tags: education, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

How to solve the integral for $J_1{(2x\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}})}$ at $[0,\pi]$? If solving by Matlab, please provide me the source. Thank you!

Comment: What's this "x"? Do you mean $\int_0^\pi J_1(2\sin\frac\theta2)d\theta$? If so, that's $\sqrt\pi\,\mathbf H_{1/2}(2)$ where $\mathbf H_{1/2}$ is a Struve function: see [Watson](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseontheory00watsuoft#page/374), p. 374, formula (3).

Comment: I interpreted it as $\int_0^\pi J_1(2 x \sin(\theta/2)) \, d\theta$, which equals $(1-\cos(2x))/x$ (the Struve function can be evaluated in closed form when its index is half an odd integer).

Comment: @HenryCohn Agreed on both counts!

Answer (score 6):

A simple analytical result is derived from the series representation of $J_1$:

$$J_1(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+1)!} \left ( \frac{z}{2}\right )^{2 k+1} $$

as well as the integral

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} du \, \sin^{2 k+1}{u} = \frac{2^{2 k}}{\displaystyle (2 k+1) \binom{2 k}{k}}$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, J_1\left (2 x \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \right ) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+1)!} x^{2 k+1} \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin^{2 k+1} {\frac{\theta}{2}} \\ &= 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+1)!} x^{2 k+1} \int_0^{\pi/2} du \, \sin^{2 k+1}{u} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)(2 k+1)} \frac{(2 x)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k)!}\\ &= \frac1{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+2)!} (2 x)^{2 k+2}\\ &= \frac{1-\cos{2 x}}{x}\end{align} $$